# How to count comma separated values in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Here i've a number of values that are comma separated. now i just want to count them.

[image: Click to load image]

the values are

```
"160,159,158,157,156,155,143,141,140,139"
```

like:

```
160: 1
159: 2
158: 3 and so on..
```

**And here in my try**

```
 var checkValues = $('input[name=checkboxlist]:checked').map(function()
                   {
                        return $(this).val();
                   }).get();
 var i = '"'+checkValues+'"'.split(',');
 alert(i);
```

Please guide me, where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want the count not the sum.

split it on *,* and get the length

```js
var val="160,159,158,157,156,155,143,141,140,139";
console.log("Count : ",val.split(",").length);
```

If you want the index of each value and count

then use

```js
var val="160,159,158,157,156,155,143,141,140,139";
val.split(",").forEach( (x,y) => console.log(x," : ",y+1));
```

the `y+1` is there because `y` is position and starts from 0

Comment: Best answer.Ignore others

Comment: Thanks @sagar. but it gives me Count : blank

Answer (score 2):

```js
var numbers = "160,159,158,157,156,155,143,141,140,139";

// If you just want to count them :
var count = numbers.split(',').length;
console.log(count);

// If you want to link a value and its 'index'
var result = {};

numbers.split(',').forEach((e, i) => { 
  result[e] = i + 1;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

To count the **number of occurrences of each value** you can use `[].reduce()`

```
const result = "160,159,158,157,156,155,143,141,140,139"
   .split(/,/)
   .reduce((counter, val) => {
      if (!counter.hasOwnProperty(val)) counter[val] = 0;
      counter[val]++;
      return counter;
    }, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by turning it to array using String.split,

and then use reduce to count your values

```js
var ans = "160,159,158,157,156,155,143,141,140,140,139".split(',').reduce((prev,curr)=>{
  if (prev[curr]) prev[curr]++;
  else prev[curr] = 1;
  
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the brackets.
Chaining function has priority over standard numeric operation. Should be:

```
var i = ('"'+checkValues+'"').split(',');
```

To group and count each distinct value you can use approaches other proposed, like:

```
var result = i.reduce(function(prev, curr){
  if (prev[curr]) { prev[curr]++; }
  else { prev[curr] = 1; }
  return prev;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var values = "160,159,158,157,156,155,143,141,140,139";
var final  = values .split(',').reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, 
 currentIndex) {
      accumulator[currentValue] = currentIndex;
       return accumulator;
},{});
```

Hope it helps you!